# How to round up prices with PHP

Tags: php

i want to round up prices in PHP

e.g. i have the price `£74.32` i want to round to the closet `5.00` or if above 5 then `9.00` and the decimals i always want to be `.95`..

For example

```
£74.32 would be round up to £75.95

£93.78 would be round up to £95.95

£67.87 would be round up to £69.95
```

I attempted to round up prices with the below but i'm stuck on rounding the number to either 5.00 or 9.00

```
$price = ceil($price) - "0.05";
    return $price;
```

How do i accomplish this?

Comment: Thats not mathematically logical so to speak, so there is not going to be a builtin function to do that. You are going to have to write something yourself to achieve this functionality. Which means this looks more like a specification than a request for help with some code you cannot get working, and **off topic**

Comment: ignore the decimals, as i know how to do that. How do i round up to the nearest 5 in PHP?

Comment: thanks for this but if it is above 5 i'd like to round up 10?  Is this possible.. i'm not good at math.

Comment: this is for a woocommerce function @RiggsFolly,  i have to round up all the prices in the database and i'm making a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
if ($price % 10 > 5) {
    $newPrice = floor($price / 10) * 10 + 9.95;
} else {
    $newPrice = floor($price / 10) * 10 + 5.95;
}
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/vZUditLz)

Comment: Thanks this is just what i wanted.  Works on my function.

Comment: No prob. Sometimes it is not obvious how to translate needs into algorithms !

Comment: Also for future reference what does `$price % 10` mean?

Comment: It is the modulus. As described [here](http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic), it is the remainder of a division. So here the remainder of price divided by 10.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to multiply the original value before the round. This is often used to round to some decimal numbers, if the function does not support a decimal digits argument.

```
$rounded = round($value * 100) / 100;
```

In this case the factor would be 2 / 10 (= 0.2)

```
ceil(74.32 * 0.2) == 15
```

If you divide it with the same value you get the desired limit

```
ceil(74.32 * 0.2) / 0.2 == 75
```

Now just subtract the 0.05:

```
$rounded = ceil($price * 0.2) / 0.2 - 0.05
```

Comment: `round($value * 100) / 100;` is equivalent to `round($value, 2);`

Comment: Like I wrote "if the function does not support a decimal digits argument." I just used it as a starting point.